# Правильно ли расставлены запятые? Объясните, пожалуйста!

Tags: запятые

Эту, казалось бы, мелочь, я заметила с первого раза.

Comment: Смотря о чем идет речь, а точнее, перед `бы` как по мне, запятая лишняя, т.к. теряется смысл, и мелочь становится не причастна к предложению. Мои варианты:
1: `Эту казалось бы мелочь, я заметила с первого раза.`, 
2: `Эту, казалось бы мелочь, я заметила с первого раза.`

Так не теряется смысл предложения.

Comment: Mr LLENN, определитесь: комментируете или отвечаете! Переписка здесь не проходит.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно так:

*Эту, казалось бы, мелочь я заметила с первого раза.*

Обособляется вводное выражение ***казалось бы***. Перед "я" нет причины ставить запятую.

Answer (score 2):

[**казалось (бы)**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_305), *вводное слово*. То же, что «как будто бы, словно».
Необходимо выделить его запятыми.

Рассмотрим предложение без вводной конструкции.
***Эту мелочь я заметила с первого раза***  — это простое предложение (без сравнительного, причастного или деепричастного оборотов; без однородных членов), в котором запятая перед **я** не нужна.

**Эту, казалось бы, мелочь я заметила с первого раза.**

*Слушая эту, **казалось бы,** никчемную, непритязательную болтовню Петрухи, занимавшего тем самым себя и своих попутчиков, Авдий думал о своем…* (Ч. Айтматов. Плаха)

*Но не только школьная психология, приспособленная для нужд преподавания, крепко держится за эту, **казалось бы**, ожидающую только устранения теорию, но и представители...* (Л. С. Выготский. Учения об эмоциях)

Answer (score 1):

*Эту, **казалось бы**, мелочь // я заметила с первого раза.*

Итак, запятая после слова "мелочь" не нужна, но почему же ее ставят?

Это типичная проблема "лишних запятых", когда запятой обозначают все слышимые паузы, а по правилам постановка знаков должна объясняться **грамматически**.

Но вся грамматика в данном случае — это обособленное **вводного слова** в простом предложении.

**А пауза тогда откуда?** Дело в том, что простое предложение обычно состоит из двух фраз, между которыми делается небольшая пауза, обозначающая перелом интонации (от повышения к понижению тона). Вот эта пауза и провоцирует нас на постановку запятой.

Comment: Интересный анализ!)

Comment: Артем, в принципе Ваш ответ всем понятен: грамматических причин для постановки третьей запятой нет. Но тема лишних запятых уже стала здесь обсуждаться, поэтому  я  ее тоже рассмотрела.

Comment: Да, Вы молодец! :)